# Requiring only an email or phone number to complete Ajax form

Tags: php, ajax

With a contact form I have, I am trying to only require an email OR a phone number to be entered to validate a form.
I saw a similar post here [Php Contact Form - Optional Fields (trim)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770372/php-contact-form-optional-fields-trim), however it isn't applicable code-wise to the ajax form I'm working off of.
Here is my code

```
define( "RECIPIENT_NAME", "John Smith" );
define( "RECIPIENT_EMAIL", "john@example.com" );
define( "RECIPIENT_PHONE", "987-555-1234")
define( "EMAIL_SUBJECT", "Visitor Message" );

$success = false;
$senderName = isset( $_POST['senderName'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "",          $_POST['senderName'] ) : "";
$senderEmail = isset( $_POST['senderEmail'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "",     $_POST['senderEmail'] ) : "";
$senderPhone = isset( $POST['senderPhone'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\\0-9]/", "", $_POST[‘senderPhone’] ) : ””;
$message = isset( $_POST['message'] ) ? preg_replace( "/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Subject:|Content-    Type:)/", "", $_POST['message'] ) : "";

if ( $senderName && $senderEmail && $senderPhone && $message ) {
$recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . " " . RECIPIENT_PHONE . ">";
$headers = "From: " . $senderName . " <" . $senderEmail . ">" <" . $senderPhone . ">";
$success = mail( $recipient, EMAIL_SUBJECT, $message, $headers );
}

if ( isset($_GET["ajax"]) ) {
  echo $success ? "success" : "error";
} else {
the rest of the code :)
}
```

I assume that the answer lies in a change of coding here

```
$senderName && $senderEmail && $senderPhone && $message
```

Sorry, I'm a novice and I apologize if the answer is blatantly obvious and thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use the OR operator `||` and group that part of the condition in parens `(` `)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $senderName && ($senderEmail || $senderPhone) && $message ) {
    // if no email set as sender
    if(!$senderEmail)$senderEmail = 'noreply@mydomain.com';
```

This line seems kinda odd

```
$recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . " " . RECIPIENT_PHONE . ">";
```

To field should be something like this

```
$recipient = "My Name <example@example.com>";
```

But yours have your phone number there too. Try this

```
$recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work (but I appreciate the speedy response, btw)

`// If all values exist, send the email
if ( $senderName && ($senderEmail || $senderPhone) && $message ) {
  $recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " (<" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . "> || <" . RECIPIENT_PHONE . ">)";
  $headers = "From: " . $senderName . " (<" . $senderEmail . "> <" . $senderPhone .">)";
  $success = mail( $recipient, EMAIL_SUBJECT, $message, $headers );
}`

this is how i incorporated it; can you tell me what I missed?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$senderPhone = isset( $POST['senderPhone'] ) ? 
    preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\\0-9]/", "", $_POST['senderPhone'] ) : "";
```

use

```
$message .= isset( $_POST['message'] ) ? 
    preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\\0-9]/", "", $_POST['senderPhone'] ) : "";
```